# Supressing INFO messages in R

Tags: r, jdbc, rjdbc

I want to supress INFO messages on execution of some statement.
Any help?

```
connection = IIP.JDBCConnection()
17/08/30 09:22:01 INFO jdbc.Utils: Supplied authorities: 10.177.119.89:10000
17/08/30 09:22:01 INFO jdbc.Utils: Resolved authority: 10.177.119.89:10000
17/08/30 09:22:01 INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Will try to open client 
transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.177.119.89:10000/default
```

it is showing these INFO messages. I wish to avoid them

Comment: What package is `IIP.JDBCConnection` from?

Comment: you could use `invisible(ur_function)` to suppress the output of ur_function

Comment: You have `suppressWarnings`, `suppressMessages`, `sink` (for `print`). But I'm unable to find `IIP.JDBCConnection` so can't say what is producing these messages.

Comment: That is loggng by Java, you need to configure the logging properly, and how that is done depends on the library that produces this logging.

Comment: @useR it is a function of IIPR package. tried all sink, invisible and supressmeassages functions, but no help.